# Evaluation of $\int (\arctan x)^2 dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Integrate

> $$\int (\arctan x)^2 dx $$

(in terms of elementary functions , if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a result by Maple,

$$ 2\,i \left( \arctan \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {
\left( 1+ix \right) ^{2}}{1+{x}^{2}}}+1 \right) ^{-1}-2\,i \left( 
\arctan \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}$$
$$ +2\,\arctan \left( x \right) 
\ln\left( {\frac{ \left( 1+ix \right) ^{2}}{1+{x}^{2}}}+ 1 \right) -
i{Li_{2}} \left( -{\frac { \left( 1+ix \right) ^{2}}{1+{x}^{2}}
} \right) \,,$$

where the $Li_{s}(z)$ is the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) function.

> You can follow this technique:
>
> Write $\arctan(x)$ in terms of $\ln$ as
>
> $$ \frac{1}{2}\,i \left( \ln  \left( 1-ix \right) -\ln  \left( 1+ix \right) \right)\,,$$ then use the binomial theorem to expand $ \arctan(x)^2 \,.$

Comment: Can the polylogarithm be avoided ?

Comment: @Souvik:This is not an elementary integral. You have to deal with these kind of functions.

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal:Thanks for verifying that it's not elementary.

Comment: @Souvik:you are welcome.